# WordPress: count custom fields values and echo the number

Tags: php, database, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-fields

Was looking around for a while and couldn't find a solution. So my question is:

I have a custom field (checkbox), for example: `my_custom_field_checkbox`. And I have 5 posts that have this checkbox checked. I need to get that number five somehow to use it in the front end, for example:

**Admin:**

[checkbox] I read this book

**Front end:**

People who read that book (**5**)

So, how could I do that? Thank you!

### EDIT:

---

Ok, I was examing this question and googling and I came up with that code, it works, and it allows me to count different values of the same custom field:

```
$rbBuildCatsArray = array('cat_top_managers_args'=>__('Top management, managers','ibchrrb'),'cat_car_business_args'=>__('Car Business','ibchrrb'),'administrative_staff'=>__('Administrative staff','ibchrrb'),'banks_insurance_leasing'=>__('Banks, insurance, leasing','ibchrrb'),'safety_guard'=>__('Safety, guard','ibchrrb'),'accounting_finance_enterprise_economy'=>__('Accounting, finance, enterprise economy','ibchrrb'),'public_service_nonprofit_organizations'=>__('Public service, non-profit organizations','ibchrrb'),'design_art_entertainment'=>__('Design, art, entertainment','ibchrrb'),'home_staff_service'=>__('Home staff, service','ibchrrb'),'procurement_supply_fea'=>__('Procurement, supply, FEA','ibchrrb'),'internet_it_telecom_communication'=>__('Internet, IT, telecom, communication','ibchrrb'),'logistics_transport_storage'=>__('Logistics, transport, storage','ibchrrb'),'marketing_advertising_pr'=>__('Marketing, Advertising, PR','ibchrrb'),'healthcare_jobs'=>__('Healthcare Jobs','ibchrrb'),'science_education_consulting'=>__('Science, education, consulting','ibchrrb'),'hr_department_hr_training'=>__('HR department, HR, training','ibchrrb'),'part_time_seasonal_work'=>__('Part-time, seasonal work','ibchrrb'),'sales'=>__('Sales','ibchrrb'),'industry_agriculture'=>__('Industry, agriculture','ibchrrb'),'jobs_for_youth'=>__('Jobs for Youth','ibchrrb'),'workmen_laborers'=>__('Workmen, laborers','ibchrrb'),'restaurateurs_chefs_waiters'=>__('Restaurateurs, chefs, waiters','ibchrrb'),'retail_trade'=>__('Retail, trade','ibchrrb'),'media_publishing_printing'=>__('Media, publishing, printing','ibchrrb'),'sports_fitness_beauty_salons'=>__('Sports, fitness, beauty salons','ibchrrb'),'real_estate'=>__('Real estate','ibchrrb'),'tourism_hotels'=>__('Tourism, hotels','ibchrrb'),'services_repair_and_maintenance'=>__('Services, repair and maintenance','ibchrrb'),'jurisprudence'=>__('Jurisprudence','ibchrrb'));

 foreach($rbBuildCatsArray as $category=>$label){
    $unqCatVariable = '$cat_'.$category.'_args';
    $unqCatVariableCount = '$cat_'.$category.'_count';

   $unqCatVariable = array('post_type' => 'paibcresume','posts_per_page' => -1,'meta_query'=>array(),'meta_key' => '');
   $unqCatVariable['meta_query'][] = array('key'=>'rbwwcategoryhidden','value'=>$label,'compare'=>'LIKE');
   $unqCatVariableCount = new WP_Query($unqCatVariable);

   echo '<div>' . $label . ' ' . $unqCatVariableCount->post_count . '</div>';
 }
```

### EDIT:

---

Heres the screenshot of what I was talking about. I have custom field in my custom post type. I get values of that custom field and count them **(pink area).**

[image]

Comment: Did you tried something for it , if yes then please share.........

Comment: What is your question, can you explain ... are you show count that how many people read a book or how many posts are checked !!!!

Comment: @deemi I count how many checkboxes are checked.

Comment: O my brother i think you don't get my point  please read my comment with peace mind

Comment: @deemi, how many posts are checked, if i get right what you mean :)

Comment: OK now i get your point

Comment: @deemi, I added a screenshot to make it 100% clear :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use both inbuilt function as well as direct sql for this.

```
query_posts('meta_key=my-key-name&meta_value=my-meta-value');
echo $wp_query->found_posts;
```

or use sql query

```
$sql = "SELECT count(DISTINCT pmeta.post_id)
FROM $wpdb->postmeta pmeta
JOIN $wpdb->posts posts ON (posts.ID = pmeta.post_id)
WHERE pmeta.meta_key = 'my-meta-key'
AND pmeta.meta_value = 'my-meta-value'
AND posts.post_type = 'post'
AND posts.post_status = 'publish' ";

$count = $wpdb->get_var($sql);
echo $count;
```